# How to show labels above bar in MPAndroidChart horizontal Chart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to display labels above each bar not on top of every bar. Suppose I have five bars then I want labels on top of every bar. I have tried this code

```
            YAxis leftAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();
            leftAxis.setSpaceTop(15f); //Prevent 100% from overlapping
            YAxis rightAxis = barChart.getAxisRight();

            XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
            xAxis.setTextSize(15);
            rightAxis.setEnabled(false);
            leftAxis.setEnabled(false);


            BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
            data.setValueTextSize(10);
            data.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());
            barChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); //set whatever color you prefer
            barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);// this is a must
            barChart.setData(data); // set the data and list of lables into chart
            barChart.setDescription("");  // set the description
            barChart.animateY(2500);
    //        barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);

            Legend l = barChart.getLegend();
            l.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: No bro I was not able to resolve @ArpitJ.

Comment: I have resolved something similar, but not sure if this is what you want. You wanted labels to appear on top of bars or horizontally above?

Comment: Horizontally above I want

Comment: were you get any solutions? I am facing the same problem

Comment: No luck bro @MarGin